# I have a query on which I would like to have all numbers except what between 1 <> -1

Tags: sql-server

```
select  
    sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) as ECART
from
    Solde_View
group by 
    having sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) > -1
    and having sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) < 1
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score -1):

You have some syntax error and try this:

```
select  
    sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) as ECART
from
    Solde_View

   WHERE NOT(sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) >= -1
    and sum(COALESCE (somme_fac_reg, 0)) - sum( COALESCE (RESTE, 0)) <= 1)
```

Comment: Thank u very much again, any otherwise becouse this not  i want ??